# Can you print an integer in scientific notation?

Tags: c, io, formatting

I know that in C, you can print floats and doubles in scientific notation using "%e" and "%le" respectively and that you can print integers using "%d". Is there a way to print integers using scientific notation? I tried "%de", but that didn't work. For instance, I want 6000000 to print as 6e+06.

Comment: Convert it to `double` and print that.

Comment: That's ingenious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you print an integer in scientific notation?

A simple approach is to convert to a `double` and then print. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918498/can-you-print-an-integer-in-scientific-notation#comment127084131_71918498)

```
printf("%e\n", (double) some_int_type_object);
```

This is insufficient when the integer precision and value exceeds `double` - typically about 53 bits.

Recommend to use `long double` to handle wider integer types.  This still may not meet precision requirements.

```
printf("%Le\n", (long double) some_integer_type_object);
```

To *portably* handle 64-bit integers obliges custom code.